# node: could not initialize ICU (check NODE_ICU_DATA or --icu-data-dir parameters)

Tags: node.js, node-modules, icu

I was trying to upgrade node version on our CI environment from node 6 to node 8. I updated the full-icu version as well.

the `$NODE_ICU_DATA` is set to `/usr/lib/node_modules/full-icu`

but still get this error

```
node: could not initialize ICU (check NODE_ICU_DATA or --icu-data-dir parameters)
```

Any idea, how to fix this?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to run `npm install` including the `full-icu` package. It's `full-icu`'s postinstall step which downloads the appropriate bits for the currently executing node.  Note that multiple files may show up in the `full-icu` directory, that's OK.

If you already had `full-icu` installed, but upgraded Node.js in between:

```
npm rebuild
```

fixes the issue.

Comment: For others, this worked for me: `yarn add full-icu` and then `node NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu ...`

Comment: You can also just do the tried-and-tested method of nuking `node_modules` and reinstalling

Comment: yarn add --force

Answer (score 30):

If you already had `full-icu` installed, but did upgrade node in between:

`npm rebuild` does fix the issue.

Answer (score 8):

If you want use Node.js with full-icu and Docker, you can use example of Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /icu
RUN npm init -y && npm install full-icu
ENV NODE_ICU_DATA=/icu/node_modules/full-icu

WORKDIR /project
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

It's works for me.