# Windows 10 - node: could not initialize ICU (check NODE_ICU_DATA or --icu-data-dir parameters) error

Tags: node.js, node-modules, icu

An issue similar to this post: [node: could not initialize ICU (check NODE_ICU_DATA or --icu-data-dir parameters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296555/node-could-not-initialize-icu-check-node-icu-data-or-icu-data-dir-parameters?rq=1)

I get the same error message:"node: could not initialize ICU (check NODE_ICU_DATA or --icu-data-dir parameters" with the fresh node installation. It is a brand new computer with Windows 10 Pro system version 10.0.17763 Build 17763. I have tried installing version 10.16.0 LTS and version 12.6.0 current from node.js website. In both cases I have exactly the same error, does not matter if I run as admin or a normal user. I cannot use the solutions described above as npm will not run (same error). I have no idea what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort it out. As it turns out, other software was using the environment variable: NODE_ICU_DATA.
 I have removed NODE_ICU_DATA variable, restarted computer and installed node again.
 It is working fine now.